# URI.getHost() with special characters

Tags: java, utf-8, uri

I am trying to get the domain name of the current url with

for case: özgür.com and I think because of the special character code is throwing exception, what is right way to fix this?;

```
private static String getDomainName(String url) throws Exception {
    if(!url.contains("http")){
        url = "http://" + url;
    }

    URI uri = new URI(url);
    String domain = uri.getHost();

    return domain.startsWith("www.") ? domain.substring(4) : domain;
}
```

uri.getHost() returns null; and method throws NullPointerException.

Comment: @Lino It is. Furthermore they open completely different websites.

Comment: Which exception is it throwing? It'll surely give you some idea about what's going wrong.

Comment: @MysteriousWolf "Lino" I don't why but problem is fixed, when I used URL instead of URI "Kayaman" uri.getHost() returns null; and it gives me NullPointerException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about replacing URI with URL? `URL uri = new URL (url);`

Comment: It is working,thanks, but I wonder why is it not working with URI?

Comment: In the URI class, there is a comment which says that the class uses US-ASCII alphabetic characters for dealing with URIs/URLs (because of the RFC2396 standard)